Create a WiFi to WiFI bridge using nmcli (WiFi Repeater)
Im using an raspberry pi zero 2. I would like to set it up to become a WiFi repeater. How could I use nmcli to set this up?

Do you have the hardware available? A repeater will need one antenna for receiving, the other for sending. A RPI zero 2 has only one 2,4 GHz module on board.

@FelixJN that's not technically correct; you can serve multiple networks via the same antenna, given the chipset supports that. And that might be the problem here. Also, I believe the RPi Zero to be a bit anemic in its bandwidth, so it's probably not the device I'd want to run wifi access across, even if the wifi chipset supports it.
